# plotly::ggplotly is breaking for certain facet-wrap data

Tags: r, r-plotly, ggplotly

I have a problem combining `plotly::ggplotly` (v4.7.1) with `facet_wrap` (v3.0.0) that I can't seem to generalise but is reproducible with a particular dataset (summary metrics for a set of tweets):

```
require(tidyverse)
require(plotly)
d = read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/geotheory/21c4eacbf38ed397f7cf984f8d92e931/raw/9148df79326f53a66a8cc363241a440752487357/data.csv')
d = d %>% mutate(key = fct_reorder(key, n)) # order the bars
p = ggplot(d, aes(key, n)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
  facet_wrap(~ set, scales='free', nrow=1) +
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) + coord_flip()
print(p)
```

[image]

Enter ggplotly:

```
print(ggplotly(p))
```

[image]

This seems to relate to the combination of `nrow=1` and `scales='free'` arguments. Any ideas about the cause?

Comment: Also reported to [github repo](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1301).